# Display Purchase Order Header/Item

Tags: sapui5, treetable

I have a requirement to show PO header nodes that have columns from structure1 (fields from EKKO) when user click expand the header, it should show their items with column from structure2 (fields from EKPO).

When all rows are collapsed it is just a table with the PO header details.

I'm thinking of using tree table but my question is that is it possible for tree table to have parent node with one  structure and child node with different structure?
If tree table is not possible for this requirement, Is there something else that I can use for this requirement?

[Sample Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhYgX.jpg)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately for the tree table the columns will still have to be the same. But i think you can load the item related contents of the table as popover to the row in the header table. 
You can see the UI might look like these
[image: Basic UI]
[image: Popin UI]

The code would be something like this

```
var oPopOver = new sap.m.Popover({
            placement:sap.m.PlacementType.Vertical,
            visible : true, // boolean
            placement : sap.m.PlacementType.Right, // sap.m.PlacementType
            showHeader : true, // boolean
            title : undefined, // string
            modal : false, // boolean
            offsetX : 0, // int
            offsetY : 0, // int
            contentWidth : undefined, // sap.ui.core.CSSSize, since 1.9.0
            contentHeight : undefined, // sap.ui.core.CSSSize, since 1.9.0
            enableScrolling : true, // boolean
            verticalScrolling : true, // boolean, since 1.15.0
            horizontalScrolling : true, // boolean, since 1.15.0
            content : [ new sap.m.Table() ]
        });

        this._oPopover = oPopOver;
```

Embedding the Popover to a control

```
sap.ui.getCore().byId("idStart1").getController()._oPopover.openBy(oEvent.getSource());
```